# How can I generate Bearer code for coinbase authentication?

Tags: shell, send, coinbase-api

The code below is used for sending BTC from a coinbase account to another

```
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/2bbf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659ede/transactions / -X POST \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ -H 'Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c' \ -d '{ "type": "send", "to": "1AUJ8z5RuHRTqD1eikyfUUetzGmdWLGkpT", "amount": "0.1", "currency": "BTC", "idem": "9316dd16-0c05" }'
```

But I don't know how to obtain the bearer code in bash. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a bearer ID you must use the Oauth 2.0 functionality Coinbase provides.  See the Coinbase API/Oauth 2.0 documentation and concentrate on the tutorial provided there.  The result will be a bearer Id.